# Runtime.HandlerNotFound with generated JS in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aws-lambda

I'm creating a Lambda as an alerting system for a web site that I use a lot. The site uses Google's Firebase Real-time DB and I've pieced together code to do what I want by looking at the site's JS code. For this reason, I'm writing the Lambda that I need in TS instead of a language that I actually know... so I'm a backend and graphics engineer lost in the world of webpacks etc.

My problem is that once I've ran my code through webpack I get a `Runtime.HandlerNotFound` from the Lambda runtime, i.e. it's not supporting the `handler` symbol from the JS file specified as an entry point in the Lambda. My zip contains a single file named `notifier.js` in the root and the precise error I get is the following:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage": "notifier.handler is undefined or not exported",
```

The Lambda function has been generating with terraform with `notifier.handler` as the entrypoint.

My project structure is the following:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
src/notifier.ts
```

File contents are the following:

`src/notifier.ts`:

```
export const handler = async (event: any = {}): Promise<any> => {
    console.log('Hello World!');
    const response = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
    return response;
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.84",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/notifier.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'notifier.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

I have compiled the code with the following commands:

```
tsc src/notifier.ts
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
cd dist && zip notifier.zip notifier.js
```

Any ideas where the problem is? It looks like the code that is output by the TypeScript compiler contains the correct export, but webpack then somehow removes it. Since I need to use Firebase and lots of other libraries, it would be much easier to get webpack working so I don't need to create a layer with node_modules etc.

EDIT: If I zip up the JS code produced by running the TypeScript compiler, I get the following:

```
Test Event Name
foo

Response
"{\n  \"key1\": \"value1\",\n  \"key2\": \"value2\",\n  \"key3\": \"value3\"\n}"

Function Logs
START RequestId: bc5f77e8-cd67-4be4-8ee1-e6ff1996aae6 Version: $LATEST
2021-10-30T10:23:03.793Z    bc5f77e8-cd67-4be4-8ee1-e6ff1996aae6    INFO    Hello World!
END RequestId: bc5f77e8-cd67-4be4-8ee1-e6ff1996aae6
REPORT RequestId: bc5f77e8-cd67-4be4-8ee1-e6ff1996aae6  Duration: 18.65 ms  Billed Duration: 19 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB  Init Duration: 139.77 ms

Request ID
bc5f77e8-cd67-4be4-8ee1-e6ff1996aae6
```

In other words, it's Webpack that is breaking the code. Webpack version that I have is:

```
% npx webpack --version
webpack: 5.61.0
webpack-cli: 4.9.1
```

Output by TypeScript compiler when running it for `notifier.ts`:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.handler = void 0;
var handler = function (event) {
    if (event === void 0) { event = {}; }
    return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var response;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            console.log('Hello World!');
            response = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
            return [2 /*return*/, response];
        });
    });
};
```

Output of Webpack when running the above JS code through it:

```
(()=>{"use strict";({482:function(n,t){var e=this&&this.__awaiter||function(n,t,e,r){return new(e||(e=Promise))((function(o,i){function u(n){try{a(r.next(n))}catch(n){i(n)}}function l(n){try{a(r.throw(n))}catch(n){i(n)}}function a(n){var t;n.done?o(n.value):(t=n.value,t instanceof e?t:new e((function(n){n(t)}))).then(u,l)}a((r=r.apply(n,t||[])).next())}))},r=this&&this.__generator||function(n,t){var e,r,o,i,u={label:0,sent:function(){if(1&o[0])throw o[1];return o[1]},trys:[],ops:[]};return i={next:l(0),throw:l(1),return:l(2)},"function"==typeof Symbol&&(i[Symbol.iterator]=function(){return this}),i;function l(i){return function(l){return function(i){if(e)throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");for(;u;)try{if(e=1,r&&(o=2&i[0]?r.return:i[0]?r.throw||((o=r.return)&&o.call(r),0):r.next)&&!(o=o.call(r,i[1])).done)return o;switch(r=0,o&&(i=[2&i[0],o.value]),i[0]){case 0:case 1:o=i;break;case 4:return u.label++,{value:i[1],done:!1};case 5:u.label++,r=i[1],i=[0];continue;case 7:i=u.ops.pop(),u.trys.pop();continue;default:if(!((o=(o=u.trys).length>0&&o[o.length-1])||6!==i[0]&&2!==i[0])){u=0;continue}if(3===i[0]&&(!o||i[1]>o[0]&&i[1]<o[3])){u.label=i[1];break}if(6===i[0]&&u.label<o[1]){u.label=o[1],o=i;break}if(o&&u.label<o[2]){u.label=o[2],u.ops.push(i);break}o[2]&&u.ops.pop(),u.trys.pop();continue}i=t.call(n,u)}catch(n){i=[6,n],r=0}finally{e=o=0}if(5&i[0])throw i[1];return{value:i[0]?i[1]:void 0,done:!0}}([i,l])}}};t.__esModule=!0,t.handler=void 0,t.handler=function(n){return void 0===n&&(n={}),e(void 0,void 0,void 0,(function(){return r(this,(function(t){return console.log("Hello World!"),[2,JSON.stringify(n,null,2)]}))}))}}})[482](0,{})})();
```

Comment: You say you have a JS file but then write `src/notifier.ts` - is it `.ts` or `.js`?

Comment: Fixed that. The main input is TS. For this example the TS compiler produces working code, but when the JS file is put through Webpack to create CommonJS code, then it stops working.

Comment: "My zip contains a single file named notifier.js" - is that also valid?

Comment: Yes. notifier.ts -> tsc -> notifier.js -> webpack -> notifier.js and the last file is in that zip. The notifier.js file after the first step works in Lambda, the last one doesn't. I need to last one to work to use firebase etc.

Comment: Also added the outputs of tsc and webpack, since they weren't too big for SO.

Comment: Probably not needed but was looking for any red flags - typically you would set up webpack to directly convert the `.ts` file to `.js` without manually compiling; try https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#basic-setup and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: I guess you simply shouldn't use webpack. Or somehow configure it to output a commonJS module, not a browser bundle.